expo run:android - Could not find device with name
I am new to React Native and Expo. Trying to run a project on an android phone. I have connected via USB, and can see the phone under adb devices:
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
H0E9DE1LV0390200146     device

However, expo doesn't seem to find this device:
$ npx expo run:android --device H0E9DE1LV0390200146
CommandError: Could not find device with name: H0E9DE1LV0390200146

What am I doing wrong?
